# Qt- Widget inside a widget with custom layout

Tags: qt

I am designing a custom widget which is a group of 16 pushbuttons of custom shape, all arranged in a specific shape. I have seen all examples of custom widget but nothing seems to help. I cannot apply any standard layout to my widget.

Below is the image represents what my custom widget should look like- each hexagon is a push button

[image]

Comment: Is QML an option for you?

Comment: I am using Qt C++ designer. Have not worked with qml. It is a desktop application